# Rebuild items in select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

```
<select id="edit-attributes-1" class="form-select required" name="attributes[1]">
<option selected="selected" value="">Please select</option>
<option value="62">2XL</option>
<option value="66">2XS</option>
<option value="63">3XL</option>
<option value="11">L</option>
<option value="10">M</option>
<option value="8">S</option>
<option value="14">XL</option>
<option value="12">XS</option>
</select>
```

How can rebuild in order?
In brackets - the value. For it can catch.

```
3XS     (63)
2XS     (66)
XS      (14)
S       (8)
M       (10)
L       (11)
XL      (14)
2XL     (62)
3XL     (63)
```

Comment: Where are you getting the values from?

Comment: Where we obtain values ​​- harder than the script (I think so).

Comment: do you mean : your html is generated (or at least, you can't change it) and you want to change the order or the option list after the page was loaded through javascript / jquery ?

Comment: More precisely, there is a sort but it does not work. And I think it really rearrange the script.

Comment: It appears that you are currently sorting in lexicographical order. What you want to do is change the sorting algorithm so that it follows a pre-defined order that you hard-code in.

Comment: Hard to hold the position of these points - an acceptable solution

Comment: This is a bit like reading crossword clues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to sort the option elements in the correct order without adding a new attribute, but it would be much preferable to have them sorted server-side.

```
/**
 * Convert a size string to a numeric value.
 *
 * A size string is one of the letters S, M or L (small, medium or large)
 * optionally preceded by an X, or a number and an X.
 *
 * This function will return NaN if the input is invalid and is not
 * case-sensitive. The result may be zero or negative.
 */
function sizeValue(size) {
    var sizes = { S: -1, M: 0, L: 1 },
        value = sizes[size[size.length - 1].toUpperCase()];

    if (typeof value == 'undefined') {
        return NaN;
    }

    if (size.length > 2) {
        // Assume strings of at least 3 characters match /\d+X[SML]/
        value *= parseInt(size.substr(0, size.length - 2), 10) + 1;
    }
    else if (size.length > 1) {
        // Assume two letter strings match /X[SML]/
        value *= 2;
    }

    return value;
}

// Now use the sizeValue function to sort the option elements.
var options = $('#edit-attributes-1 option').get();
options.sort(function(a, b) {
    // I'd prefer to use Node.textContent here, but this is compatible with
    // elderly versions of IE.
    a = $(a).text();
    b = $(b).text();

    return sizeValue(a) - sizeValue(b);
});

// Reinsert the option elements in the select in their new order.
$('#edit-attributes-1').append(options);
```

Here it is in action [on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexb/LC8Au/).

Answer (score 2):

You can give your options an order attribute:

```
<option value="62" order="8" >2XL</option>
<option value="66" order="1" >2XS</option>
<option value="63" order="9" >3XL</option>
...
```

and then sort them using [this component](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/):

```
$("select").find("option").sortElements(function(a, b){
    var aIndex = parseInt(a.attr("order"));
    var bIndex = parseInt(b.attr("order"));
    return aIndex > bIndex;
});
```

Comment: Thank you! And how better to add an attribute in this case?